# URL Rewrite is not working for http to https redirection on IIS

Tags: iis

I have two applications hosted under default Web Site on IIS 10.
For one application(for which I am using default port:443) I am able to redirect http request to https using URL Rewrite.
but for other application I am not able to achieve this(It has other port number eg:9000).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30533616/http-to-https-redirect-iis-8-5-not-working-properly