# Blazor/IIS Http force Redirect to Https not working with rewrite rule

Tags: c#, iis, blazor

### The issue

I have a Blazor app that is hosted with IIS. I have an issue where any link that does not explicitly use https shows a 404 and does not direct to https

For example if you go to:

```
app.domain.com -> 404  
http://app.domain.com -> 404  
https://app.domain.com -> Successful
```

### Things I've already tried

I have a IIS URL Rewrite Rule from other answers and this guide:
[Namecheap](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9953/38/iis-redirect-http-to-https/),  [How to force HTTPS using a web.config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823010/how-to-force-https-using-a-web-config-file)

Unchecking and Checking "Require SSL" in the ISS settings per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42588503/8582360)

In web.config changing URL to hard code the URL domain and use R:1,

```
url="https://app.domain.com/{R:1}"
```

instead of

```
url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}"
```

per [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/936655)

Adding app.UseHttpsRedirection(); to Program.cs and

```cs
    builder.Services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
    {
        options.RedirectStatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.PermanentRedirect;
        options.HttpsPort = 443;
    });
```

per [Enforce HTTPS in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)

### My current code

Here's my rewrite rule:

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect HTTP to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="SeeOther" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

and my Program.cs:

```cs
    // <<<< BUILDER.SERVICES.ADDSINGLETON... >>>>
    builder.Services.AddResponseCompression(o =>
    {
        o.EnableForHttps = true;
        o.Providers.Add<BrotliCompressionProvider>();
        o.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
        o.MimeTypes = ResponseCompressionDefaults.MimeTypes.Concat(
            new[] { "image/svg+xml" });
    });
    builder.Services.Configure<BrotliCompressionProviderOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.Level = CompressionLevel.Optimal;
    });
    builder.Services.Configure<GzipCompressionProviderOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.Level = CompressionLevel.Optimal;
    });
    
    var app = builder.Build();
    // <<<<  APP.SERVICES.GetRequiredService... >>>>

    // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment() && !app.Environment.IsStaging())
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    
    if(!app.Environment.IsProduction())
    {
        StaticWebAssetsLoader.UseStaticWebAssets(app.Environment, app.Configuration);
    }
    
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseResponseCompression();
    
    app.MapBlazorHub();
    app.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
    
    app.Run();
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: Have you looked at the HSTS setting in IIS? It's a configuration setting which will automatically redirect HTTP connections to HTTPS at application level? What version of IIS are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a port 80 binding for the Site, where I just had 443 per [Bob Cares](https://bobcares.com/blog/iis-redirect-not-working/). This fixed the issue!!!

Comment: https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html Because if you didn't configure a proper binding, the HTTP requests go to the Default Web Site instead, and 404 from there is normal.